# Encode message in json on txt file?

Tags: php, json

I have created a log library that write some trace on a txt file, all working good but I need to format the message in json encode, in particular I have this function:

```
private function Message($level, $mex, $ctx)
{
    $date = getTimeStamp($this->settings['dateFormat']);
    $message = "[{$date}] [{$level}] {$mex} ";
    $message .= PHP_EOL.indent(contextToString($ctx));
    return $message.PHP_EOL;
}
```

now this is the variables values:

`$level` =>  debug 
`$mex`    =>   System executed 
`$ctx`   =>

`[0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "john" ["username"]=> string(6) "foo" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "jack" ["username"]=> string(3) "foo" }`

now In the condition I append the context to the message with an external function for have a better message formatting. The final result of `$message` is like this:

```
`[26-02-2016 16:08:40.392436] [debug] System executed.  
 0: array( 'name' => 'john', 'username' => 'foo' )  
 1: array( 'name' => 'jack', 'username' => 'foo' )`
```

so a simple file content is like this:

```
[25-02-2016 16:55:09.497203] [exception] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or 
 view not found: 1146 Table 'test.pdd_userss' doesn't exist 
 0: array(
  'Stack' => 'Stack trace... ""
  'ID' => 'john foo'
 )
[25-02-2016 16:55:09.497857] [info] Sistema executed. 
   0: array(
      'ID' => 'john foo'
   )
[25-02-2016 16:55:13.255716] [info] System done.
```

What I need to do is parse each message in the function `write`

```
private function write($mex)
{
    if(fwrite($this->_handle, $mex) === false)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException('check the file permission');
    }
 }
```

the `write` function is called after the execution of `Message` function, in the first place I format the message and later I write it on the file. Now what I need to do is encoding each message in json format so I can parse the whole txt file simple in other project, how I can do this?

Comment: why don't you use **Log4PHP** ?

Comment: @HalayemAnis why I should use a prepared solution? I want learn and make things.

Comment: why reinventing the wheel ... ? if you want learning something nice, joinn an opensource team, that's will be great :)

Comment: @HalayemAnis For reinvent the whell you should know how to make it :)